# Force MS Word to use the same bullet in nested lists

Tags: microsoft-word, bullets

In MS Word, if you try indenting a list item, it gives you an [ugly open circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHiCW.png). How can I make it not change the bullet type on indent and have it always use a filled circle?

Answer (score 2):

The best way in Word to do what you want is to make a Style you want and edit the Style to do Bullets the way you wish.

Otherwise, without Styles, you would need to change Normal.dot to change Bullets.  This will affect every document, so I recommend Styles.

Comment: i agree. See http://shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets20072010.html to get complete control over bullets.